# Fetch Date form other website...in php

Tags: php, curl, fetch

I want to fetch all phone from this website (olx.com.pk).

I have found that function but they will fetch date single phone number from single link of this site (olx.com.pk)

```
<?php

    error_reporting(0);
    $ch = curl_init("http://olx.com.pk/item/samsung-galaxy-tab3-16gb-white-IDSUu7h.html#7aae8d1c9a");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $cl = curl_exec($ch);       

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($cl);
    //$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

    $number     = $xpath->query("//strong[@class='xx-large']//text()");

    echo "<h1>". $number->item(0)->nodeValue ."</h1>";

?>
```

I want to fetch all phone number at one...

is it possible to get all number?

Comment: what do you mean all phone number? if you look at the page, there's only one phone number in there

Comment: You can have a look at this page [link]http://olx.com.pk/computers-laptops-accessories/[link] there are lot of post and one post have one number and I want to fetch the all page phone numbers.

Is this possible to fetch all numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Here is slightly simplified version of same code:

```
// suppress DOM warnings
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);   
$url = "http://olx.com.pk/item/samsung-galaxy-tab3-16gb-white-IDSUu7h.html#7aae8d1c9a";

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLfile($url);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$items = $xpath->query("//strong[@class='xx-large']");

// loop through items to retrieve node values
foreach ($items as $item) {
    echo "<h1>". $item->nodeValue ."</h1>";
}
```

This code will fetch URL and select all strong[@class='xx-large'] nodes. Values for individual nodes are retrieved inside foreach loop.

P.S.
There is only one phone number on indicated URL and as a final result you can only see one phone number.

Comment: Yes I know, there are one phone number in this page.
But there are lot of pages which have many also phone number and I want to fetch all at once is it possiable?

http://olx.com.pk